# DNS resolution problem with OpenBSD

Tags: dns, openbsd, resolv.conf, host-name-resolution

During boot up, messages flashed on my computer screen, among which are the following:

```
DHCPACK from 192.168.200.1
bound to 192.168.200.12----> renewal in 432600 seconds
```

The contents of my **/etc/hosts** file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

The contents of my **/etc/resolv.conf** file:

```
#Generated by fx0 client
nameserver 192.168.1.1
lookup file bind
```

Other relevant information:

A. My machine running OpenBSD 5.7 beta is used as a desktop client

B. It is connected to a router which is used to access the internet

C. Connections to the internet are configured to use DHCP

D. I prefer to use my own DNS servers, not those of supplied by the router or the ISP

I am able to surf the internet without a VPN connection. However after connecting to a VPN server, I am unable to surf the internet.

I encountered a similar problem on a machine running Debian Wheezy. After I installed the package **resolvconf** and added my preferred DNS servers to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, I am now able to surf the internet even with a VPN connection. (I noticed there is no package resolvconf for OpenBSD.)

How do I fix the above DNS resolution problem?

Comment: When you are connected using the VPN have you verified that you can actually reach your name server?  Fire up the VPN and then make sure you can ping it.  If not, then try and make contact to a public nameserver like OpenDNS (208.67.222.222) and use dig to try and resolve a few names.  Dig will let you specify the nameserver you wish to use.  If you can't reach any nameservers then you must figure out why your packets aren't getting there.  If you can reach the nameservers then use traceroute to examine the path packets are using. That should give you a starting point for resolving your issue.

Comment: @unclejamil `When you are connected using the VPN have you verified that you can actually reach your name server? Fire up the VPN and then make sure you can ping it.` I'm unable to ping it and also unable to make contact with a public nameserver such as Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4).

Comment: If you can't ping the dns servers that you wish to use then you certainly won't get any name resolution.  :)  This sounds more like a routing issue than a dns resolution issue.  Once the VPN is configured properly than we can turn back to the dns resolution (if that still won't work..) What VPN are you using?  And how is it configured?  Perhaps it is best to post as much info as possible associated with the configuration of your VPN.  Also if this turns out to be a VPN configuration you may want to kill this posting and open up a different question associated with your VPN.