# Add more DNS nameservers in OpenBSD

Tags: dns

I wish to add more DNS nameservers such as 8.8.8.8 in OpenBSD 5.7. I understand that the current version of OpenBSD allows up to a maximum of three DNS nameservers.

I have read the man pages related to the following relevant topics of networking in OpenBSD:

**hostname.if**

```
http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/hostname.if.5?query=hostname.if&sec=5
```

**dhclient**

```
http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/dhclient.8?query=dhclient&sec=8
```

**resolv.conf, resolv.conf.tail**

```
http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/resolv.conf.5?query=resolv.conf.tail&sec=5
```

**dhclient.conf**

```
http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/dhclient.conf.5?query=dhclient.conf&sec=5
```

**ifconfig**

```
http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/ifconfig.8?query=ifconfig&sec=8
```

Which of the above items must I edit in order to add more DNS nameservers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to specify the nameservers that the system uses (which I'm guessing you are, based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215745/unable-to-surf-internet-with-vpn-on-openbsd) you asked before), you simply need to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.

At a minimum, it should look something like:

```
lookup file bind
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I've specified Google's [public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) servers there, but amend the `nameserver` lines as necessary to use others (eg, your ISP's DNS servers, [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/), etc).

For more information on the file contents and other values you can include, see the `resolv.conf` [manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/resolv.conf.5?query=resolv%2econf).

Comment: The first line of my `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `192.168.1.1`. I don't know how it got there. My router's default gateway is `192.168.220.1`. I removed it by becoming a superuser (root) first and using a text editor for the purpose. After reboot, it reappeared. I tried it many times and failed. First question: Is it safe for me to remove it? Second question: If yes, how to remove it *permanently*?

Comment: @virvegto If your `resolv.conf` is getting automatically updated, I can only think it's the DHCP client on your OpenBSD machine that's doing it. The server it's getting its IP from is pushing that IP to it. The the [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#DHCPclient) for more information. Basically, remove the `domain-name-servers` option from `/etc/dhclient.conf` to stop `/etc/resolv.conf` from being updated automatically. Alternatively, you can configure your DHCP server to pass the correct DNS server(s) to your OpenBSD machine.

Comment: `The server it's getting its IP from is pushing that IP to it`. I'm guessing it's my ISP that pushing its DNS to me. You see, my subscription with my ISP is for dynamic IP addresses, not static ones. `Basically, remove the domain-name-servers option from /etc/dhclient.conf to stop /etc/resolv.conf from being updated automatically.` If I do that, will I be able to surf the internet? `Alternatively, you can configure your DHCP server to pass the correct DNS server(s) to your OpenBSD machine.` I don't have a DHCP server and don't know how to configure and use one.

Comment: @virvegto Ok, if that DNS server is coming from your ISP you will need to make sure you can connect to public DNS servers before disabling `resolv.conf` updates. You can test this by removing your ISP's DNS server from `resolv.conf` and replacing it with the Google entries and seeing if you can still lookup hostnames (eg, `nslookup www.openbsd.org`). As an aside, what is your router's IP address?

Comment: `Ok, if that DNS server is coming from your ISP you will need to make sure you can connect to public DNS servers before disabling resolv.conf updates.` How do I disable resolv.conf updates after connecting to public DNS servers? Will doing so break my internet connection or worse lead to instability of the operating system?

Comment: @virvegto If the public DNS servers work, you will need to change `/etc/dhclient.conf`, as I mentioned in an earlier comment. As long as you can connect to the DNS servers, changing the setting shouldn't "break" your internet connection or lead to instability.

Comment: `As an aside, what is your router's IP address?` It's 192.168.177.1. A few days ago it was 192.168.220.1.

Comment: I read the man pages regarding `resolv.conf`. Instead of adding two more DNS nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf` file, can we add them via `/etc/resolv.conf.tail`?

Comment: @virvegto You can, but your ISP's DNS server will remain there.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies and help. I hope it isn't too much to ask of you but I'd be grateful if you could answer my question referenced by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216462/remove-uninstall-desktop-environment-from-second-user-account-on-openbsd

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the code correctly, the maximum number is now 5.

- ASR_MAXNS defined in [asr_private.h](https://github.com/robertbachmann/openbsd-libc/blob/733584208f7956b544a1b54ccc35aa1134614c51/asr/asr_private.h#L104)
- ASR_MAXNS used in [asr.c](https://github.com/robertbachmann/openbsd-libc/blob/733584208f7956b544a1b54ccc35aa1134614c51/asr/asr.c#L589)

So you could change it in `asr_private.h` and re-compile ([make obj](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html)?).

But why are you doing this?  If it's anything like Linux/glibc, each query is done in series, with a 5-second timeout, so even going beyond 3 implies the query will take at least 15 seconds if the first three aren't working.

Does your application wait that long for DNS lookups?

You may be better off running a caching nameserver locally, for example [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), [Unbound](https://calomel.org/unbound_dns.html), or [BIND](https://calomel.org/dns_bind.html).

See also: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.misc/209494

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that the maximum is 5, not 3.

Comment: `Does your application wait that long for DNS lookups?` Yes, it does. I don't know why. Firefox takes a long time, about 45 seconds, launch on OpenBSD 5.7.

Answer (score -1):

- To release current lease, run (as `root`)

  ```
  ~# dhclient -r interface
  ```
- To obtain a new lease from your vpn_gateway which will update `/etc/resolv.conf`:

  ```
  ~# route_vpn_gateway=(ipv4 gw_addr)
  ~# echo "prepend domain-name-servers $route_vpn_gateway;" > /etc/dhclient.conf
  ~# dhclient interface
  ```

Comment: Could it be that the `route_vpn_gateway=(ipv4 gw_addr)` was meant to be `$(ipv4 gw_addr)`?

Comment: I get the environment variable $route_vpn_gateway supplied from openvpn as part of configuring the vpn