# Remove/Uninstall desktop environment from second user account on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, desktop-environment, uninstall

During the installation process of OpenBSD 5.7, I created a user account, user1, belonging to *wheel* group.

Subsequently I installed a desktop environment after logging into my user account.

This morning I logged into my root account to create a second user account, user2. It also belongs to *wheel* group.

After logging into my second user account, I discovered that it had the desktop environment identical to the one of the first user account.

I issued the command:

```
sudo pkg_delete -c gnome
```

and the error message was:

```
Package not found
```

Any suggestions on how to remove the desktop environment from the second user account? For the second user account I just wish to have the bare minimum that OpenBSD offers its users.

Comment: You probably did install the DE systemwide, right? To be sure: how did you install the DE?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pkg_delete` is almost certainly *not* what you want to do - that will remove GNOME system-wide.

I assume you have a non-GNOME desktop environment installed in addition to GNOME? If so, GDM (the login manager) should present it as an option on the graphical login screen.

Comment: `Using pkg_delete is almost certainly not what you want to do` I couldn't even if I wanted to. As stated in my original post, the operating system returned an error message.

Comment: @virvegto Exactly, but I was just expanding on that and saying you were going down the wrong route trying to remove the `gnome` package.

Comment: `that will remove GNOME system-wide.` What exactly did you mean by that statement, please? I installed Gnome DE on a user account, not root account. `I assume you have a non-GNOME desktop environment installed in addition to GNOME?` Yes. After installing OpenBSD's base system, I logged into the first user account using `xdm`. After installing Gnome DE on it, I'd to change `xdm_flag` to `NO` so that I can boot into Gnome.

Comment: @virvegto How did you install GNOME? If with `pkg_add`, it's installed system-wide and available to all users. You should install `gdm` as the login manager and use that instead of `xdm` - it will let you choose desktop before logging in.

Comment: `How did you install GNOME? If with pkg_add, it's installed system-wide and available to all users.` Yes, I did use `sudo pkg_add gnome` to install the desktop environment but it was done on the first user account, NOT on the root account.

Comment: @virvegto `sudo` runs the following command as root, so you **did** install GNOME as root.

Comment: `You should install gdm as the login manager and use that instead of xdm - it will let you choose desktop before logging in.` Sorry but I don't understand what you meant by that statement. FYI `gdm` is automatically installed when I `sudo pkg_add gnome`. As you stated in a different post, `gnome` is a meta-package.

Comment: `sudo runs the following command as root, so you did install GNOME as root.` Thanks for that statement. It's become clear to me now. But you know what? There's no way for a user to install packages on a user account without resorting to `sudo` command, is there? You'll receive `Permission denied` if you issue `pkg_add gnome` while you are in a user account.

Comment: @virvegto You **should** install GNOME as root, so you did the correct thing. If you don't and don't install it system-wide, you're going to have all sorts of issues. If `gdm` is installed, you'll need to configure it to start on boot and disable `xdm`. That will let you choose a desktop on graphical login.

Comment: `If gdm is installed, you'll need to configure it to start on boot and disable xdm.` Thanks for your clarification. I get it now: there's no way to remove Gnome DE from my second user account without removing it also from the operating system. *However*, I can reverse the process by disabling `gdm` and re-enabling `xdm`. Doing so will allow me to login with a bare GUI, without the Gnome interface. Is that correct?

Comment: @virvegto With `gdm` you can also login to a bare GUI and no desktop environment. Just select a different desktop at the login screen - `fvwm` (the default) should be presented as an option.

Comment: `Just select a different desktop at the login screen - fvwm (the default) should be presented as an option.` No, there's no option to select which desktop to use at the login screen. Which version of OpenBSD are we talking about?